# Qual a diferença entre os design patterns Data Mapper e Active Record?

Tags: design-pattern, orm

Gostaria de saber quais as principais diferenças entre estes dois design patterns.

Tenho esta dúvida pois ao saber das novidades do CakePHP 3.0 vi a mudança do design pattern utilizado pelo framework.

Atualmente na versão 2.x é utilizado Active Record e agora será utilizado o Data Mapper.

**Bônus:** Como isso vai afetar a modelagem da camada Model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ambos padrões tratam da forma como você controla sua camada de persistência em um projeto orientado a objeto em bases relacionais. Os dois padrões foram propostos por [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/) no livro "*Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*". Tentando explicar os padrões:

## Active Record

No Active Record o objeto possui suas operações básicas de CRUD nele mesmo. Dessa forma, fica mais fácil consultá-lo. Exemplificando em PHP seria mais ou menos assim:

```
class Customer 
{
    // Necessário injetar a base aqui
    protected $db;

    // Propriedades do objeto (colunas)
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function do_something() {
        $this->bar .= uniqid();
    }

    public function save() {
        if ($this->id) {
            $sql = "UPDATE customer SET name = :bar WHERE id = :id";
            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam("name", $this->name);
            $statement->bindParam("id", $this->id);
            $statement->execute();
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES (:name)";
            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam("bar", $this->name);
            $statement->execute();
            $this->id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
}
```

Em minha classe de negócio, para manipular esse objeto, é simples, bastaria chamar os métodos dele mesmo, **sem delegar para uma classe terceira**. Por exemplo.

```
class BusinessLogic {
    public function saveNewCustomer() {
        $customer = new Customer($db);
        $customer->name = 'Meu Cliente';
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

## Data Mapper

Já no Data Mapper sua classe não possuirá nenhum método relativo ao CRUD ou suas operações. Somente haverá possíveis *getters* e *setters* dos atributos (dependendo da linguagem) e alguns métodos como `clone()`, `toString()` e outros, se necessário. Dessa forma esse objeto fica mais "limpo".

Sendo assim, para trabalhar com um objeto no padrão Data Mapper, você deverá **passar o objeto para uma classe terceira que realizará as operações implementadas** (geralmente um DAO).

Vamos exemplificar:

```
// Classe só com os atributos
class Customer  {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}
```

E então um DAO que realizará as operações em cima do objeto `Customer`.

```
class CustomerDAO {

    // Necessário injetar o banco ou conexão aqui
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function saveCustomer(Customer &$customer) {
        if ($foo->id) {
            $sql = "UPDATE customer SET name = :name WHERE id = :id";
            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam("name", $foo->name);
            $statement->bindParam("id", $foo->id);
            $statement->execute();
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES (:name)";
            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam("name", $foo->name);
            $statement->execute();
            $foo->id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
}
```

E na minha classe de negócio:

```
class BusinessLogic {
    public function saveNewCustomer() {
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->name = 'Meu Cliente';
        $dao = new CustomerDAO($db);
        $dao->saveCustomer($customer);
    }
}
```

## Finalizando

Bom, eu não vou falar qual é melhor ou pior. Ambos padrões tem suas vantagens e desvantagens. Eu já trabalhei com ambos. Em Java com Data Mappers e em Ruby on Rails com Active Record. Teste os dois. Há diversos frameworks em diversas linguagens. Veja alguns em PHP:

### PHP - Active Record

A maioria dos frameworks PHP implementa sua própria solução Active Record. O CakePHP também assim. Além do Cake tem alguns outros:

- [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/);
- [Laravel](http://laravel.com/);
- [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter);
- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).

Da uma olhada, se puder, no [Active Record do Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

### PHP - Data Mapper

- [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: Muito obrigado, ficou realmente claro!

Comment: A resposta ficaria perfeita se colocasse aqui as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um.

Comment: Só há um equívoco aqui: Synfomy é um framework agnóstico de "Model", desde que ele é mais "centrato" em HTTP, como Django. Geralmente quem usa symfony, integra-o com Doctrine ou Propel. Mas em Symfony é com você a parte do model.